# Open PDF file in browser from Oracle directory

Tags: oracle, pdf, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I am working on an Apex Application and I have a PDF file in an oracle directory (in the database server filesystem), now I want the client to open it when he clicks a button.

I searched similar problems but I only found scenarios where the file is stored in a database column which is not my case.

Comment: how do you save the files in the first place

Comment: Saving files worked fine for me. I followed this tutorial
https://apex4help.blogspot.com/2020/01/how-to-store-blob-file-outside-oracle.html however preview files didn't work because in his tutorial he has the tomcat and the database in the same server and he created a directory inside the tomcat. Here is the preview tutorial https://apex4help.blogspot.com/2020/01/preview-image-from-directory-in-oracle.html

Comment: what he explains is how to make a directory acceible fer the webserer, i can't see expet secirity why you can do it for d e or f or where ever you stored it in the first place

Comment: Yes, it's just a workaround he made and it didn't work for me.

Comment: what is the error

Comment: It doesn't retrieve the correct path of the file it shows file not found.

Answer (score 0):

In order for a file to be accessible from a browser, it needs to be stored in a directory that is visible to the webserver.
Oracle APEX doesn't consist of files, but mostly of metadata that is generated from within the database. ORDS is configured out of the box to serve content that is generated from within the database - *not static files*

There is one exception. By default, ORDS also servers the apex static files - this maps to a physical directory on the server.

There are 2 options to access your own files:

- ORDS can also be configured to map a physical "root" directory under which html  files (or pdf) can be stored in an optional directory structure. Check the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/23.1/ordig/about-REST-configuration-files.html#GUID-006F916B-8594-4A78-B500-BB85F35C12A0) for that. The configuration parameter for that is "standalone.doc.root" - I believe that is what you're looking for.
- or you could use another webserver like Glassfish or Tomcat and create a virtual directory to serve your pdf files.